# How to get the name of the current user in delphi?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Hi there i am using delphi FM2 with XE3 in windows 8.

The problem im having is that i want the user to press a button and then navigate to a subfolder located in appdata ex. C:\Users\Kobus\AppData\Roaming.minecraft

Everybody has a diferant username so this wont work.

So i use this code to get the username:

```
function GetCurrentUserName : string;
const
  cnMaxUserNameLen = 254;
var
  sUserName     : string;
  dwUserNameLen : DWord;
begin
  dwUserNameLen := cnMaxUserNameLen-1;
  SetLength( sUserName, cnMaxUserNameLen );
  GetUserName(PChar( sUserName ),dwUserNameLen );
  SetLength( sUserName, dwUserNameLen );
  Result := sUserName;
end;

username := GetCurrentUserName;
```

Then i say `ShowMessage('C:\Users\'+username+'\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\');` to check the output.

And the output i get is : 'C:\Users\Kobus' for some reason the rest of the path name is lost.

What i need to be displayed is : 'C:\Users\'Kobus'\AppData\Roaming.minecraft\saves\'

Thanks.

Comment: On a Windows XP system, you mean `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>` etc. Possibly. You don't know what the path is, even if you know the user name. Use the [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `dwUserNameLen` contains the length of the string, including the trailing zero terminator. So when you do:

```
SetLength(sUserName, dwUserNameLen);
```

this results in `sUserName` being set to `'Kobus#0'`. At some point you then pass this to a Windows API dialog function that treats the string as a null-terminated string, and truncates the string at the stray null-terminator.

So you fix it like this:

```
SetLength(sUserName, dwUserNameLen-1);
```

Note that you should also check the return value of `GetUserName` in case that call fails:

```
if not GetUserName(PChar(sUserName), dwUserNameLen) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

or a rather crisper variant:

```
Win32Check(GetUserName(PChar(sUserName), dwUserNameLen));
```

One final point. This is the wrong way to get hold of the roaming app data folder. For a start you are assuming all sorts of implementation details. Your approach will fail on older versions of Windows which use different naming patterns. Or some future version of Windows. Or the current versions that have been configured in a different way.

The right way to do this is to ask the system where the roaming app data folder is. Do that using `CSIDL_APPDATA` (for older Windows versions), or `FOLDERID_RoamingAppData` (for modern Windows versions).

Comment: +1 for the 'One final point' part, which is by far the most important part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help ill try do as you said in the final point.

Comment: Personally i'd do `SetLength( sUserName, StrLen(sUserName) );` here. Or even lazy `sUserName := PChar(sUserName);`. Since this Win32 APi call does not return multiple strings separated by multiple zeroes, `dwUserNameLen` can be just ignored.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't need to dig too long to find a snippet :).
So what I use in my own app, after summarising the hints, becomes:

```
//=================================================================
procedure TMainF1.UserTestClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  cnMaxUserNameLen = 254;
var
  sUserName     : string;
  dwUserNameLen : DWord;
begin
  dwUserNameLen := cnMaxUserNameLen-1;
  SetLength( sUserName, cnMaxUserNameLen );
  Win32Check(GetUserName( PChar(sUserName), dwUserNameLen ));
  sUserName := PChar( sUserName );
  label_user.Caption := UpperCase(sUserName);
end;

//== works well with D7
```

Answer (score 1):

i Think your question is one of the [XY Problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Your actual problem that you want to read the full path of `%AppData%\.minecraft\saves\`

And you thinking in how to read the current `Username`

Look at [CSIDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
function GetShellFolder(CSIDLFolder : integer) : string;
begin
  SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
  SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, PChar(Result), CSIDLFolder, false);
  SetLength(Result, StrLen(PChar(Result)));
  if (Result <> '') then
    Result  := IncludeTrailingBackslash(Result);
end;

....

//Usage
ShowMessage(GetShellFolder(CSIDL_APPDATA)+'.minecraft\saves');
```

**UPDATE**

Alternative

Check the [GetHomePath](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath) function in `System.IOUtils` unit.

Will do the same result that you want for multi platforms.

```
uses System.IOUtils;

procedure TForm17.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ShowMessage(TPath.GetHomePath() + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + '.minecraft\saves');
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
username := GetEnvironmentVariable('username');
```

sets `username` to the current user's name, obviating the complexity.

Comment: An answer that contains only code is generally a poor answer. You should attempt to explain what the code is trying to do, and how it solves the problem, and answers the question that was asked.

Comment: The biggest issue with this answer, IMHO, is that it fails to adress the major problem in the OP's approach.

Comment: Well, if you wish. I'd suggest it was a reasonably obvious though. Answered the question asked, "How to get the name of the current user in delphi." Simplest method IMO.

Comment: The question was simply how to get the data - would you expect anyone searching for an answer to the question asked to implement the operation using that method? The question was not "how do I find the current user's minecraft.exe'

Comment: You should also be aware that there's no guarantee that the environment will contain that variable. But the API call always gives the right answer.